# Why is intermolecular potential energy given in 'per mole'?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, units, molecular-dynamics

I was just wondering that if intermolecular potential is the interaction potential energy of two atoms/molecules, then why do we give its value in J/mole? I don't understand why 'per mole' specification is required?
This is the situation where I am confused. When using LJ potential in molecular dynamics simulation, the $\epsilon$ parameter has value of the order of 1 kJ/mole. If I am using only 1000 particles in my simulation, what value of $\epsilon$ should I use?

Comment: You could also write it as "per two molecules" but which is easier?

Comment: I have edited my question to specify the situation which confused me.

Comment: After giving it a little thought, I think the given potential energy is the average potential energy. So, in my case, I should divide 1kJ by Avogadro's number and then multiply by the number of particles in my simulation. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

I think about these things in microscopic units, like eV/atom.  However measurements are made with macroscopic amounts of material and tend to be tabulated in macroscopic units.  The two units aren't that different ($\rm 1\,eV/atom \approx 100\,kJ/mol$) but pointless uncertainty can be introduced in the conversion.

Comment: +1 If the conversion to eV serves its purpose as being intuitive, I think the uncertainty in the conversion is of not much significance.

Answer (score 0):

The mole essentially denotes "number of molecules". When you say "per mole", you are implying "per molecule", which is highly desirable since it directly converts a macroscopic property such as 'total heat released during reaction' to a microscopic property such as 'heat released per molecule'.

Since $\epsilon$ is an intensive function as it is per molecule, the number of molecules don't matter, whether 2 or 1000.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably still use kJ/mole for consistency. It is clear what you mean, just like you might use "1 g/L" even when dealing with quantities less than a litre. In general, when working with multiples of units derived as ratios of other units, it is better to scale the denominator than the numerator. Compare "km/s" and "m/ms". Both have a thousand times the value of m/s but the first one makes thus much more apparent.